# Configuring Jetty HTTP/2 Client to use my HostnameVerifier implementation

Tags: java, jetty, http2

I am using Jetty HTTP2 Client 9.4.12 to support HTTP/2 server connection. It's working fine but on top of verifying the certificate, I also want to verify the Hostname using my `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` implementation. According to the doc https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.12.v20180830/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html I can use `setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS")` to enable hostname verification but how do I configure Jetty to use my implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: The `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier` is a feature of `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` and is only used as a backup if default URL hostname verification fails.  Why do you need such a backup implementation in Jetty's `HttpClient`?   I ask, as there's often a different way to accomplish the same end goal.  (What's important in my question is the goal, not the exact steps to get there)

Comment: @Joakim thanks for the reply. Its because we have various other conditions while verifying the hostname which is given as a configurable option to the users of the application. For HTTP/1.1, we were using Apache Http client which provided this feature pretty straightforward but since support for Http/2 is still in beta in Apache, we moved to Jetty client and now need provide that same configurations to the users for http/2 as well. Is there any other interface to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty's HttpClient does not support `javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier`.

An enhancement request exists for this ...

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3154

Feel free to comment on the open enhancement requesting it, and providing an example of how you would use it.

Answer (score 0):

The support has been added in Jetty v9.4.15.v20190215.

```
final SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
sslContextFactory.setHostnameVerifier((hostname, sslSession) -> {
    // logic to verify hostname
    return false;
});
```